# php script working on locally on the system but not on the server

Tags: javascript, java, php, html, css

Kindly help me go through the below code to see where there are errors as the code is working locally on my system but not working well on the server. It gets to the point of moving the images to the folder, but the data doesn't get moved to the database. I have checked and checked, but can not really place my hand on the error and I will really appreciate some kind of help soon. Thank you.

```
<?php


include_once("../php/db_connection.php");
include_once("php/admin_session.php");

?>
<?php
 // ADD NEW PROPERTY
 $error_msg = '';
if(isset($_POST['title'])){
$title = $_POST['title'];
$names = $_POST['name'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$map = $_POST['map'];
$img = "../rent_images/$names";

if(isset($_FILES['product_image'])){
    foreach($_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['product_image']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['product_image']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['product_image']['type'][$key];  
        if($file_size > 2097152){
            $error_msg ='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }       
        $desired_dir=$img;
        if(empty($error_msg)==true){
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0755);        // Create directory if    it does not exist
            }
                if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
                }
                else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
                }
        }
    }
    $sql_addProduct = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO rents(id,title,name,description,price,category,location,map,date_added) VALUES('','$title','$names','$description','$price','$category','$location','$map',now())");
    if(!$sql_addProduct){
        $error_msg = '<div class="atention">Couldn\'t upload the images or property details, please try again</div>';
    }else{
       header("location: property_list.php");
       exit();
    }
}
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Admin Panel</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var pull = $('#pull');
        menu = $('nav ul');
        menuHeight = menu.height();

        $(pull).on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            menu.slideToggle();
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var w = $(window).width();
        if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')){
            menu.removeAttr('style');
        }
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<div>
    <?php include_once("template/header.php"); ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <p><a href="property_list.php"> Click Here Update Property</a></p>
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" width="100%">
                    <section id="main_content">
                        <h1>Add Product</h1>
                        <?php echo $error_msg; ?>
                        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <input type="text" class="input-login" name="title" placeholder="Title" maxlength="100"><br><br>
                            <input type="text" class="input-login" name="name" placeholder="Name" maxlength="100"><br><br>
                            <textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="description" placeholder="Detailed description"></textarea><br><br>
                            <input type="text" class="input-login" name="price" placeholder="Price" maxlength="15"><br><br>
                            <input name="category" class="input-login" placeholder="Category" maxlength="50"><br><br>
                            <input name="location" class="input-login" placeholder="location" maxlength="50"><br><br>
                            <textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="map" class="input-login" placeholder="Insert Google map address"></textarea><br><br>
                            <input type="file" name="product_image[]" multiple title="Select property images"><br>
                            <br/>
                            <button id="submitBTN">Add Product</button>
                        </form>
                    </section>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>
<div>
    <?php include_once("../template/footer.php"); ?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you might have an issue with the indirect directory names.  Apache might be executing it in a different directory

Comment: kindly expanciate more please.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one of your includes for the db-connection or the admin_session is wrong.  Assuming that you have them placed in the same folder.

Comment: the db-connection works for all the scripts in the project and that is why it is placed on the main folder while the admin-session only work for the back end. do that have an effect on the execution of the code sir?

Answer (score 0):

Open your database config file and change your user , host and password

**../php/db_connection.php**

Comment: Do you mean changing it to the one i created on the server? if that is what you mean i have done that unless you mean i should change it again. the user, host and password on the local system is different to that of the server.

Comment: Could you show your **../php/db_connection.php** file? not the passwords and things like that,please post with another password not the real one,  I just wanna see the **sintax**, of your file

Comment: okay, the connection is shown below bcos i have updated it but still geting the same error on the server side:                      <?php

    $connection = new mysqli("localhost","root","password","tim");
    if($connection ->connect_error){
 echo 'Connection not ok';
 exit();
    }

    ?>

Comment: Why localhost? Create a new data base on the Server and change This to the new config